# jQuery doesn't seem to parse JSON automatically

Tags: jquery, json, string, parsing

Here's my client-side jQuery code:

```
$.ajaxSetup ({
   contentType: "application/json",
   datatype: 'json'
});

$.ajax({
   type: "POST",
   url: "http://localhost:1234/path",
   data: JSON.stringify(myData),
   success: function(aString){
      alert(aString);
   },
   error: function(errorData){
      alert(errorData);
   }
});
```

Here is the data the server sends out:

```
200
Content-Type: application/json

"aStringsData"
```

In the alert the quotes of "aStringData" are displayed. However, I'd expect the quotes to be taken away due to the automatic JSON.parse I expect to happen from datatype: 'json'. Am I wrong on this?

Comment: JavaScript is case sensitive. `dataType !== datatype`.

Comment: Thanks much, I probably wouldn't have figured it out in quiet some time..

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The parameter is actually `dataType`, not `datatype` (JavaScript is case sensitive).

You can try with:

```
dataType: 'json' // not datatype
```

within your `ajaxSetup`;

Answer (score 0):

Your response:

```
"aStringsData"
```

is not valid `JSON` I believe, as JSON supposed to start with a `{`, right?.

You might mean

```
{
 "string": "data"
}
```

Comment: Well, it can be either an object, or a list of things (like a string), but not a string in itself, can it? (of course, I can be mistaken, but the first 3 validators I tried same to say the same)

Comment: @matt : the json page you link has 2 bolletpoints: they tell that it's an object or a list. There _is_ a definition of "value" later on, sure, but it doens't say the value alone is valid JSON as I read it.

Comment: `@`Nanne: I'm inclined to agree with you. I tried `JSON.parse('"foo"')` and it worked fine, but the RFC I read said that JavaScript parsers *could* accept non-JSON as an extension if they wanted... http://json.org doesn't do a very good job of explaining it, one way or another.

Answer (score -1):

you can try to use something like this:

```
eval(aString)
```

Comment: This doesn't come *close* to answering the question. The question is asking *why* the JSON isn't parsed automatically, not how to do it.